# How to open FoxPro DBF with memo fields in R

Tags: r, dbf, memo

I have a problem with opening a **DBF** ( resulting from Foxpro) with **Memo** fields which are stored in ***.ftp** file into R. 
I can read in a dbf using read.dbf() from package foreign, but memo fields are not read in correctly.

Any ideas how to read dbf with memo type fields into R?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "**into R**"

In order to get the Memo Field contents, you will need to use Foxpro/Visual Foxpro.

If this is a **BUSINESS-CRITICAL** project, then you should consider either purchasing a copy of VFP or hiring a contractor to export the data into your desired format.

Comment: I know how to do this in Fox pro, but i would like to do this in R which is a statistical software.